# Are masked sprites and Stencil Buffers in Unity only visible on one eye if deployed on HoloLens2?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, stencil-buffer

Is it possible that Sprite Renderer in a HoloLens2 Unity Project, which are masked via a SpriteMask are only visible on one eye in the final HoloLens2 build (UWP via VisualStudio2019 deployed on HoloLens2 device).
I also experienced the same behaviour on elements which are masked with a StencilShader.
I am using a 24-bit depth buffer for my unity project if that helps, otherways the StencilShader wouldn´t work.

Answer (score 0):

To display certain objects to one eye, for different rendering configurations, different ways need to be used.

With [MultiPass](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/StereoRenderingPath.MultiPass.html), you should be able to set a camera to render to only one eye(Camera component -> Output-> Target Eye), so doing per eye stuff is super easy. With [Stereo Instancing](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SinglePassInstancing.html), you can draw in Shader but you will need to multiply the projection matrix of the current eye.

Comment: Yes, but my problem actually is, that those sprites are displayed on only one eye what I don´t like. Every sprite which is covered by stencil or mask operations is only displayed on the right eye display of the HoloLens. I was wondering whether the reason behind that actually is the Stencil buffer or the Sprite Mask. I need those stencils and masks but I also need to see the result on both eyes.

Comment: The question I wanted to ask is, how can I use stencil buffers in shaders and in the same time be able to see the result on both eyes. Sorry, maybe I asked my Question not really good.

Comment: Which Depth buffer format are you using? According to the MRTK Doc, stencil buffer only work with 24-bit depth format: https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/hologram-stabilization.html#depth-buffer-format Besides, for example, you can find the  shader material examples in the MaterialGallery scene under MRTK/Examples/Demos/StandardShader/Scenes/.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! I was not available for a while. I am using 24 bit depth format as mentioned in MRTK Doc and the reason for this problem really is the code about stencil buffering in the corresponding shader.  If I remove the stencil-buffer code from the shader script I wrote, the Sprite is beeing displayed correctly.